# Rails 4 - Multiple yield blocks on a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to have a partial using more than one `yield` block? I wanted to use it to implement bootstrap modal boxes on my project, kinda like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <%= yield :header %>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= yield :body %>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= yield :footer %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is more or less how I was thinking of using it

```
<%= render partial: "shared/modal" do %>
    <% content_for :header do %>
        ...        
    <% end %> %>

    <% content_for :body do %>
        ...        
    <% end %> %>

    <% content_for :footer do %>
        ...        
    <% end %> %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to do this? Is this maybe a bad approach for some reason?

Comment: You're allowed to have multiple yields in the same view. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, this code does not work

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent I'm trying to do the exact same thing. Were you ever able to get this to work?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent just stumbled on an answer! See below ...

Answer (score 11):

Through much trial and error, I think I solved this in Rails 5 but needed to insert a blank `yield` in my partial in order to get it to work:

`_partial.html.erb`

```
<div class="partial">
  <%= yield %> <!--Does not do anything-->
  <div class="header">
    <%= yield :header %>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <%= yield :text %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Implemented as:

`full_layout.html.erb`

```
<%= render "partial" do %>
  <% content_for :header do %>
    <h1>Header content</h1>
  <% end %>
  <% content_for :text do %>
    <p>Text content</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tried this, the "empty" yield must come first before named yields.

Comment: weird that the empty `yield` is needed. does NOT work without it. wonder if it's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue with your render partial. Notice you have all of your content_for blocks within the render partial block.

```
<%= content_for :thing do %>
   Some content
<% end %>
<%= render partial: "blah" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem to use multiple yield blocks in your partial. Only thing is to make sure that many is actually needed. For an example content_for sections are basically placeholders for content that could vary based on the logic of the application. So, it's totally fine to use multiple yields in one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just run put an `yield` there withouth the output. This way you can also use the default block.

```html
<div>
  <% yield %>
  <div class="mt-3">
    <div class="text-2xl tracking-wide font-bold text-gray-900">
      heading
      <%= yield :heading %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="relative bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl mb-8 min-h-28">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
...
```